# What is the area around a plant that is under its phytochemicals/secondary metabolites influence?

Tags: botany, entomology, chemical-communication, allelopathy

Is there a dilution threshold as a function of distance or some general measure regarding the area around a plant that is under the influence of its phytochemicals?
I'm looking for a objective value so I can proceed with a sample of aquatic macroinvertebrates in this area. I know it is something difficult to determine because of n factors, though any general, peer-reviewd information would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. This question is interesting but currently too broad to answer. Rewording to a specific plant (or group of plants), phytochemical, and aquatic macroinvertebrate (or group) might help.

Comment: I was pretending to address the effect of secondary metabolites from the white ginger lily (Hedychium coronarium) on aquatic entomological fauna according to different distances/buffers, expecting to find some threshold for functional diversity or other response variable. This is still an incipient idea that I need to refine.

Comment: Your comment has the kind of information that we would need to answer the question, directly including it in the question usually works best for useful answers. Also, you will need to directly `@`  for them to see your comment. Though that is also not working so well for me here for some reason.